# How to get the image path from Resource file in c# windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I want to get the image from Resource folder in c# windows application? already i tried in different ways. But i dint get the correct solution.

i need the path: "c:test\windowsapp\Resouces\bar.png" instead of start-up and executable path etc.Help me

Comment: are you adding the image to a picture box or..? do you just want the path as a variable?

Comment: i have collections of image in it.i need to read the path dynamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var filePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                   .Location + @"\..\..\Resources\bar.png";
```

If your image is a valid resource, you can access it through: `Properties.Resources`

Comment: Yeah,I tried that one already. thanks for ur reply. I wanna split the path and add  "Resources\test.png".