# Constructor of a user control load file from random location

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a digital clock user control. Here is the code:

```
public partial class DigitalClockControl : UserControl
{
    public DigitalClockControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private static List<Image> Sprite;
    private static Clock data;
    public Clock Data
    {
        get { return DigitalClockControl.data; }
        set { DigitalClockControl.data = value;
        int min = data.Min;
        int sec = data.Sec;
        Min1.Image = Sprite[min / 10];
        Min2.Image = Sprite[min % 10];
        Sec1.Image = Sprite[sec / 10];
        Sec2.Image = Sprite[sec % 10];
        }
    }   

    private void DigitalClockControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Sprite = new List<Image>();
        LoadSprite();
        data = new Clock();
    }

    private void LoadSprite()
    {
        string path = Directory.GetParent((Directory.GetParent((Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().ToString())).ToString())).ToString();
        Image img;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
        {
            img = Image.FromFile(path + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png");
            Sprite.Add(img);
        }     
    }
}
```

When I tried to drag this user control to the form, it raised an error like this:

```
Failed to create component 'DigitalClockControl'. The error messages follows:'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: D:\\0.png...
```

I don't know why it loads an image from D:\. All the images are at the path above. If I copy the image to D:\, the program works fine. I tried to go to the InitializeComponent() function but cannot file any code makes the program load the image.

Edit: solved by adding user control by code in Form.cs. Thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: `GetCurrentDirectory` is exactly what it says - current directory. Any chance if you are looking for something like "directory next to my executable"?

Comment: what is the actual image location and application exe file location?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not really sure what you mean. The path variable links to where I store the images. If I copy the image to D:\ for the program to work, I can see that the path links to exactly where I want.

Comment: Check this one out [How to get the image path from Resource file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687504/how-to-get-the-image-path-from-resource-file-in-c-sharp-windows-forms) - may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should place all images into `debug\\bin\\images` folder. so, when you install the application you can find all the images in Application Folder (`Application.StartupPat + "\\Images"`).

**CODE:**

```
string path = Application.StartupPath + "\\Images";
Image img;
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; ++i)
{
    img = Image.FromFile(path + "\\" + i.ToString() + ".png");
    Sprite.Add(img);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() (that is the assembly containing your control) and use its Location Property to figure out where the root of your component is. You could put the images for your clock into a folder next to your assembly. By doing so, deployment would be easy and clear.